# How does declaring integers under multiple names work in Cpp?

Tags: c++

I am new to learning C++, and encountered this as a solution when doing practice problems.

```
int n, Petya, Vasya, Tonya, number(0);
cin >> n;
while (n--)
{
    cin >> Petya >> Vasya >> Tonya;
    if (Petya + Vasya + Tonya >= 2)
    {
        number += 1;
    }
}
```

How does the line `int n, Petya, Vasya, Tonya, number(0);` work?

Also, why is there a `number(0)` at the end of the declaration?

Comment: what does your book say about it? What exactly do you mean with "how does it work" ?

Comment: It also can be `int n, number(0), Petya(int number);`. See the answer in any C++ book. BTW Cpp is C preprocessor. What you mean is C++.

Comment: `(0)` is a fancy way of saying `= 0` (in this case). And `int a, b, c;` is the same as `int a; int b; int c;`.

Answer (score 3):

C++ allows you to declare multiple variables at the same time.  In this case, the last one of these (`number`) is also initialized to zero.

Answer (score 3):

A [*declaration statement*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations) specifies 1 or more variable identifiers of the same type, where each variable can optionally have an initializer.

So, in this example, there are 5 separate variables being declared - `n`, `Petya`, `Vasya`, `Tonya`, and `number` - all of the type `int`, and the variable `number` is initialized to `0`.

The statement in question in equivalent to:

```
int n;
int Petya;
int Vasya;
int Tonya;
int number = 0;
```